# Is this OK to redirect to `PUT`, `DELETE` methods?

Tags: html, httpbackend

In my application I have route `/users/37/verify_email`. Because action for this route updates *activation* info in database I ask client to complete this request with `PUT` method.

In application on backend there are many steps to verify. After success verification I redirect client to next step with `302 Found` with a little hack:

```
Location: /users/37/verify_email?_method=PUT
```

This looks ugly a bit for me.

Is this OK to do such redirections?

**UPD**

I follow the `REST` and when I want to delete resource I generate next link on admin page:

```
<a href="/users/37?_method=DELETE">Delete</a>
<a href="/users/37"               >View  </a>
```

If we are in browser there will be:

```
GET /users/37?_method=DELETE
GET /users/37
```

When performing `application/json` there will be:

```
DELETE /users/37
GET /users/37
```

But I am not sure is this OK to put such routes into `Location` header:

```
Location: /users/37?_method=DELETE
```

I can not find anywhere this syntax:

```
Location: DELETE /users/37
```

Comment: Why you need `_method` in query? I mean, you should check which method was used directly, not from query parameter...

Comment: @PavelŠtěrba updated question

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't follow REST in HTML forms, because you are limited for [GET and POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) method only.

Simply create URL `/users/37/delete`, do all your validation here and delete it on success. If you want to have REST API, keep it separately with JSON only interface, because you are very limited here with HTML.

Also, is very dangerous to do validation on one URL and than redirect it to URL which do deleting itself. What if your user will find out, which URL is deleting stuff? He can skip the validation.

Consider using microservices or simply call your API from backend code (API can run on your intranet only and will be accessible only from backend, not from outside).